# linux file system layout -partiton - fdisk

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-18.04, partition

I am tyring to understand linux file system layout. Why does the command work inside virtual box but not on linux shell on windows?

I tried to use the command sudo `fdisk -l dev/sda` on both my virtual box(Ubuntu) and Ubuntu on windows(from microsoft store). It didn't work on any of them but when I changed the command to `sudo fdisk -l`, it worked inside virtual box but not on linux bash shell on windows.

Inside linux shell on windows:

```
:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No such file or directory

:~$ sudo fdisk -l

fdisk: cannot open /proc/partitions: No such file or directory

:~$ man fdisk

:~$ whereis fdisk

fdisk: /sbin/fdisk /usr/share/man/man8/fdisk.8.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) - Ubuntu is a POSIX emulator which is like [Cygwin](http://x.cygwin.com/) kind of environment helps to port some Linux based commands/applications running on windows platform as windows process.

It contains an abstraction layer of a virtual filesystem (vfs) which has read-only app image & RAM based writable tmpfs and neither it doesn't have access control to read the raw devices on host system nor it emulates the raw devices for the subsystem.

from man(fdisk) :

> **Description**
>
> This command is used to create and modify the partition table, and to install the master boot (IA only) record that
> is put in the first sector of the fixed disk. This table is used by
> the first-stage bootstrap (or firmware) to identify parts of the disk
> reserved for different operating systems, and to identify the
> partition containing the second-stage bootstrap (the active Solaris
> partition). **The rdevice argument must be used to specify the raw
> device associated with the fixed disk, for example,
> /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0p0.**

So WSL-Ubuntu can't execute the fdisk command successfully since it doesn't have its own kernel to manage host resources.

On the other hand, Oracle's **[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)** is a virtualized system which imitates a fully functional OS running on bare metal. It simulates its own system-space & user-space with the help of virtualization hypervisor and manages the virtual resources via the Guest OS kernel. This is why fdisk command execution was successful on VirtualBox

Reference :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/posix-emulation-submitted.pdf

Credits: https://www.quora.com/How-is-Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux-different-from-running-Linux-on-Windows-in-a-VM